# What directory does etckeeper store its permissions / metadata in?

Tags: configuration, etc, etckeeper

In what directory does etckeeper store its metadata and permissions in?

I want to know for purposes of testing the restoration of a configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It [stores its metadata in the `/etc/.etckeeper` file](http://etckeeper.branchable.com/README/), which is also tracked in the repository used to store `/etc`.

Comment: Does that file get stored in the etckeeper repository under git...wait I guess it would because it's in /etc right?

Comment: Yes, it is stored in the repository.