# Is it always necessary to run etckeeper git commands using the vcs command?

Tags: git, etc, etckeeper

I've seen some tutorials on the internet in which people are using `etckeeper` to keep a log of their server configuration, and yet they use the `git` command directly instead of running it through the `etckeeper vcs` command.

This seems a little dangerous to me, since etckeeper is a proxy for the git command since [etckeeper has to store file permissions and meta data in the .etckeeper directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250216/what-directory-does-etckeeper-store-its-permissions-metadata-in).  Is running git commands like this dangerous to the state of the .etckeeper directory or anything else related to it?

Does it depend on which command is run?  Why or why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`etckeeper vcs` merely loads `/etc/etckeeper/etckeeper.conf` (which may, but usually doesn't set environment variables), determines which VCS system the repository uses, and calls the appropriate VCS command with the specified argument. If you know that the repository is stored under git, running `etckeeper vcs foo` or `git foo` makes no difference.

Running commands like `etckeeper commit` instead of `git commit` does make a difference, though not necessarily a critical one. To take the example of `git commit`, all the intelligence about permissions and ownership is in a hook. What `etckeeper commit` does (besides determining which VCS to use) is things like setting the author identity according to the etckeeper configuration, committing everything by default (so that `etckeeper commit` is like `git commit -a`), and passing extra flags set in the etckeeper configuration.